# Float to bottom and keep the scrollbar

Tags: css

I made a messaging system and I'm stuck with CSS. I want to display messages starting from bottom of page (like on Facebook). I used common method for this, set relative position to container and absolute position to child, but I also need scrollbar in child, and when I position messages like I explained, scrollbar dissapears.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/dL3d7/

If you remove `.messages` class from CSS you'll see scrollbar but then messages won't be on bottom.

So my question is, how to keep messages on bottom and keep the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `max-height: 200px` and `overflow: auto` to `.messages` class:

```
.messages{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 200px;/*Add this*/
    overflow:auto;/*Add this*/
    min-width:100px;/*Add this*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dL3d7/7/)

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect now

Comment: This is essentially same as I've suggested but since it uses `min-width` the div contracts to 100px. The addition of `overflow: auto` is not needed unless it's being overriden elsewhere because `overflow: auto` is the browser's default CSS value.

Comment: @DrewT It is the same, I only accepted this answer because I tested it before you answered, but your answer also works for me.

Comment: @Alen - it's all good. just putting some details in case anyone finding it later. Detailed why it works always good. :D

Answer (score 2):

In your `.messages` div you're using `position: absolute` which means you are going to have to make the `width` and `height` explicit (as you've done for `height` already in the `.messagesWrap` div)

Try this CSS:

```
.messagesWrap{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.messages{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px; /* now make the height explicit */
    width: 100%;   /* and the width too */
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/dL3d7/13/

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: relative` in `.messages`

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/umayr/dL3d7/3/)